# unable to recover data on a dynamic disk

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, data-recovery, windows-10-v1803, dynamic-disk

I had a computer with two 3TB HDDs that were Dynamic Disk mirrors of one another. I'm trying to recover data off of one of them without success.

So I plugged one of these 3TB HDDs into a USB3<->SATA adapter and, in Disk Management, see the new disk as an "Invalid" "Dynamic" disk. I right click on that disk and then click "Reactive Disk" in the resultant menu and get this error:

```
This operation is not allowed on the invalid disk pack.
```

Does this mean the disk is bad? I found lots of paid data recovery software that I can use and maybe that really is the only option available to me but I can't help but seriously wonder if that's also just the result of those software vendors just spamming Google.

I'm running Windows 10 Pro 64-bit Build 1803.

Comment: "Does this mean the disk is bad?" - You are trying to access data off an incomplete disk pack.

Comment: "You are trying to access data off an incomplete disk pack" So what do I need to do to access the data? I realize that doing so is going to break the mirror and that's fine. I just want to get at the data. That's why I was using the Dynamic Disk feature to mirror the data - the data is important to me and I want to be able to recover it on demand...

Comment: Like what happens if one disk gets physically damaged while the computer is off? At that point the disk pack is going to be incomplete too. The point of mirror'ing is to be able to recover data when failures happen. If you have to have both disks, at all times, to access data on any one disk, then idk what the point of Dynamic Disk mirror'ing is. It seems like a complete garbage feature if this is how it works...

Comment: There is a difference between attempting to recover the disk pack on the machine that created the disk pack  and attempting to read the data from a single disk from a 2-disk pack.

Comment: @Ramhound - "There is a difference between attempting to recover the disk pack on the machine that created the disk pack" The machine that created the disk pack won't turn on. I ordered a new PSU in an attempt to fix it but in-so-far as I know it could be the mobo too. And what do I do then? I suppose I could load the HDD up into Linux to see if it could read them but surely there has to be a way to do this in Windows? Or is Windows built off of the preposterous assumption that the PSU, mobo, CPU, etc, can ever fail?

Comment: Windows is not built on that assumption.  That isn't even close to what I suggested.

Comment: @Ramhound - I just want to know how to get the data off of the drive, which I guess is an attempt "to read the data from a single disk from a 2-disk pack". In a few days I figure I'll offer a bounty on this question because, semantics notwithstanding, I would like an answer. Even if the PSU does the trick this scenario seems like it's one that would be encountered easily enough such that an answer would be useful imho...

Comment: @neubert did you try testdisk? https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: See [this solution](https://windowsforum.com/threads/dynamic-disk-invalid.3906/) of using a [hex editor](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) to change in sector 0, location 1C2, the value "42" (invalid drive) to "07" (basic drive), and reboot twice. If this doesn't work, undo it and see [these methods](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/dynamic-disk-invalid.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The article
[Dynamic Disk Invalid](https://windowsforum.com/threads/dynamic-disk-invalid.3906/)
recommends using a Hex editor to change on the disk the byte indicating
the disk as "invalid drive" to "basic drive".
Several persons have indicated that this solution has worked for them.

The recommended tool is the free [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)
that can edit raw disks.

The byte to change is found in sector 0, location `1C2`.
Check that it contains the value "42" (invalid drive) and if so, change it to
"07" (basic drive).
The poster said he needed to reboot twice for this to take effect.

If this does not work, return the byte to "42", and search for a recovery utility.

One such utility is said to be
[MiniTool Partition Wizard Pro](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partition-magic-free.html),
whose use for solving the problem is described in the article
[If Dynamic Disk Invalid Issue Occurs, How to Repair It with Ease](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/dynamic-disk-invalid.html).
Unfortunately, you will probably need the paid version ($39).
A demo is available, which might mean a trial version.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issue, but with raid0 config. The easiest way to access data was to create VM in VirtualBox/VMWare Workstation and attach that SATA-USB adapter do that VM.

VM should be linux (I've choosed Ubuntu) and you need to install `ldmtool` (`apt install ldmtool`) to work with dynamic disk.

basicly easiest way to access dynamic drive of any type would be:

```
ldmtool scan
ldmtool create all
```

it will create volume in /dev/mapper/, for example `ldmtool_WIN_VOLUME`

```
ntfsfix /dev/mapper/ldmtool_WIN_VOLUME # optional, may prevent mounting read-only incorrectlly closed volume
mkdir /mnt/dynamic-disk
mount /dev/mapper/ldmtool_WIN_VOLUME /mnt/dynamic-disk
```

Answer (score -1):

THIS IS HOW YOU FIND THE LOCATION

For anyone struggling, by  section 0, location 1C2 they mean at the top of HxD where it says section leave it at 0 or change it back to 0 then reading along the left side you want to look for 000...1C0 this is the location and 2 columns into it is the location 1C2.

Row 00...1C0 , column 2 , this is the data field you change to 07